# Prevent a closed source chosen process from swapping on Windows

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management

When I run VirtualBox If I don't use VirtualBox for some time and then I come back to using it the virtual machine runs very slowly, obliviously all subsequent operation go enough fast.

How I can avoid the memory manager to put the VirtualBox's process in the swap when the application is not used ? I want that application to respond quickly even after long time of inactivity.

NOTE: That question is not the same of:

Preventing a heavy process from sinking in the swap file
Prevent an arbitrary process to use swap
Prevent process from swapping (Windows)

because **I don't have access to the source code of that application**.

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear.

Comment: @BBlake is not the same question. I can't modify the source code of the application. I'm looking forward to find a way to do it at application level, not at source code level.